# What is the proper way to remove a UIViewController from the background memory when using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller like this:

```
UINavigationController * PlacesNC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlacesNavigationController"];

[self presentViewController:PlacesNC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Once I am at the final view controller that is presented using the navigation view controller, how can I remove the initial view controller from memory?

**Edit**

In my application it is possible to present multiple UIViewControllers in this fashion. I will try to give a representation of what my stack might look like.

```
____ modal vc 5 * current view controller
____ modal vc 4
____ modal vc 3
____ modal vc 2
____ modal vc 1
____ root view controller
```

So if I have a stack like this, how can I remove vc 1,2,3 and maybe even 4 so that I can release the memory these other view controllers are using up? This may not be the correct to allow such a stack as this, but this is what I have now, and I just need a temporary fix as the iPhone 4 cannot handle the amount of memory used in a stack like this. So until I can come up with an alternate way to present my view controllers I just need to be able to remove some of them from the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, and you don't want to. It is still in the view controller hierarchy, as I show in this diagram (DrillViewController is presented, but RootViewController is still there, "behind" it):

[image]

Presenting a view controller does not destroy the presented view controller, nor should it; if it did, you would not be able to dismiss the presented view controller and find the presenting view controller still sitting there.

Moreover, in iOS 8 it is perfectly possible to present a view controller and show the presented view controller's view *in front of* the presenting view controller's view, which remains visible behind it. That, for example, is how a UIAlertController presentation works. Clearly it would be a disaster if the presenting view controller ceased to exist in that situation.

Now, it may be that what you really mean is: My view controller has *a property that uses a lot of memory*. I don't need to hang on to that when my view controller is not frontmost. So I'd like to release it when I present another view controller. In that case, just manage the memory manually: set that property to `nil` on `viewDidDisappear:`, and recover its value (somehow) on `viewWillAppear:` when the presented view controller is dismissed.

One final suggestion: Perhaps the real problem is that a presented view controller was just the wrong type of hierarchical arrangement to start with. Perhaps what you really want to do is *replace* your original view controller in the view controller with the new view controller - because you are *never* coming back to it and don't need it any longer. That is perfectly possible, but of course you'll need to set up a different hierarchy architecture.

Comment: Did you make that chart? or can you post a link to the source, if there are more such useful graphical representations of other concepts there?

Comment: I added some more information to my question. Please have a look. I think your answer is very good, but my changes might change your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: It changes nothing. I already explained how to reduce memory usage, and I already suggested possibly using a different architecture. You have not changed the problem. Now try thinking about my answer.

Comment: So are you telling me that there is no way to remove a view controller from a stack? Wether it be right or wrong... this is the answer I need.

Comment: I am telling you that there is no way to remove a view controller from a sequence of _presented view controllers_ (i.e. modal, created with `presentViewController`). There are _other_ architectures where you _can_ remove a view controller "from a stack". That is what the last paragraph of my answer is proposing - use a different architecture.

Comment: Or you could dismiss and then present, instead of presenting on top of what is already there, so you don't pile up so many view controllers. That is what I mean by "replace" in the last paragraph of my answer.